# Вывод notifycation с условием

Tags: java, android, service, уведомления

Всем долго здравствовать.

Ситуация следующая:
В зависимости от некоторых условий время от времени отправляется интент с BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE. Т.к. пользователь должен подтвердить действие, а телефон может быть заблокирован/лежать в стороне и т.п. я добавил оповещение. Весь метод пока выглядит следующим образом:

```
private void ensureBluetoothDiscoverability(Context ctx)
{
    if (bluetoothAdapter == null) return;

    if(bluetoothAdapter.getScanMode()!= BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Device was not in discoverable mode");

        nm.cancelAll();
        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 30);
        discoverableIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, discoverableIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(ctx)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setTicker("Требуется действие пользователя")
                .setContentTitle("Требуется действие пользователя")
                .setContentText("Необходимо подтвердить включение обнаружения устройства Bluetooth.")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_main)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        Notification notification = builder.getNotification();
        nm.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Device set up as discoverable");
    }
    else{
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Device already discoverable");
    }
}
```

Собственно, теперь несколько вопросов:

1. Каким образом выводить уведомления только на заблокированном устройстве, в активном режиме достаточно, например, звукового оповещения, а при вызове метода проверять, существует ли уже уведомление?

Comment: Задайте отдельные вопросы по каждому пункту. От того, в каком виде сейчас ваш вопрос форуму не будет толку.

Comment: Хорошо, тут я оставлю только один вопрос.